# Kivy Mapview: distinguish buttons pressed

Tags: python-3.x, button, kivy

Sorry for this noob question, im still learning and I find little documentation for the mapview module.

So for one screen page I have this:

```
class Mapspage(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.aboutname="hi"
        super(Mapspage, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        gl = GridLayout(cols=1)
        mapview = MapView(zoom=12, lat=55.6712674, lon=12.5938239)
        self.buttons=[]
        self.nums=range(0,len(df["name_en"]))
        for i in self.nums:
            name=list(df["name_en"])[i]
            marker = MapMarkerPopup(lat=list(df["latitude"])[i], lon=list(df["longitude"])[i])
            self.buttons.append(button(text=list(df["name_en"])[i],on_press=partial(self.pressbutton,num=self.nums[i]),size=(len((df["name_en"])[i])*7*1.05,15),size_hint=(None,None)))
            marker.add_widget(self.buttons[i])
            mapview.add_marker(marker)
        gl.add_widget(mapview)
        self.add_widget(gl)

    def pressbutton(self,num, *args):
        global aboutname
        aboutname=(df["name_en"])[num]
        chatapp.screenmanager.current = "About"
```

where I use `from functools import partial`.
The problem with my approach, despite I made sure the buttons are stored in a different variable (elements of the self.buttons list), and even made sure the numbers them self are stored in a separate list, I cant get to pass the number variable, that distinguishes the buttons (that appear when clicking the maps point), on to the pressbutton function. When I run my attempt I recieve the error, `TypeError: pressbutton() got multiple values for argument 'num'` where I think all buttons passed on their num variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with the definition of your `pressbutton()` method and its handling of keyword arguments. You can handle keywords by defining `pressbutton()` as:

```
def pressbutton(self, button_instance, num=99):
```

which defines `num` as a keyword argument and provides a default value.

Another option is something like:

```
def pressbutton(self, button_instance, **kwargs):
    num = kwargs.pop('num', 99)
```

which does the same thing.